# JS doesn't run with an asp.net update panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

The following code works without an update panel, but doesn't run when there is an update panel.  Its purpose is to clear bfcache on page entry from a back or forward browser press.  Anyone know how to get the js to run when the user hits back/foward and the page has an update panel?

window.onpageshow = function (event) { if (event.persisted) { window.location.reload() } };

Full page with update panel:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ToolkitScriptManager" />
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var js = "window.onpageshow = function (event) { if (event.persisted) { window.location.reload() } };";

                Sys.Application.add_load(js);

                var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

                prm.add_endRequest(js);
                prm.add_beginRequest(js);
            </script>

            <a href='Default.aspx'>Default</a>
            <a href='Default2.aspx'>Default2</a>
            <a href='Default3.aspx'>Default3</a>
            <a href='Default4.aspx'>Default4</a>
            <br />
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

Attempt #2

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onpageshow = function (event) { if (event.persisted) { window.location.reload() } };
    </script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ToolkitScriptManager" />
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <a href='Default.aspx'>Default</a>
            <a href='Default2.aspx'>Default2</a>
            <a href='Default3.aspx'>Default3</a>
            <a href='Default4.aspx'>Default4</a>
            <br />
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

Attempt #3

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ToolkitScriptManager" />
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var js = window.onpageshow = function (event) { if (event.persisted) { window.location.reload() } };;

                Sys.Application.add_load(js);

                var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

                prm.add_endRequest(js);
                prm.add_beginRequest(js);
            </script>

            <a href='Default.aspx'>Default</a>
            <a href='Default2.aspx'>Default2</a>
            <a href='Default3.aspx'>Default3</a>
            <a href='Default4.aspx'>Default4</a>
            <br />
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you have make string the part of the code that must be run. Remove the `"` from this line:

```
var js = 
 window.onpageshow = 
    function (event) { if (event.persisted) { window.location.reload() } };
```

And one more, you can remove that part of stript from inside the update panel and place it just before.

Comment: I tried that and putting it outside of the update panel.  See Attempt #2 in my updated post.  It still doesn't work.  This is in Safari if that helps at all.

Comment: @user1777317 You need to include also and the rest code. `Sys.Application.add_load(js)` and the other.

Comment: @user1777317 I can not help you with the part that concern the logic of your program, I can only help you with what I see as bug.